# Eclipse Tomcat creating 3 duplicate JNDI connection pools

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jndi

On one developer workstation running Eclipse Helios SR2, Windows 7 and Tomcat 6.0.32 we have a very strange case of duplicate JNDI connection pools

- Running tomcat from Eclipse
- server.xml

>

```
<Context docBase="path to web app" path="/ds-web" reloadable="true">
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/ds"
        username="ds"
        password="pass"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ds"  
        auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
        factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" 
        logAbandoned="true" 
        maxActive="30" 
        maxIdle="10" 
        maxWait="1000" 
        removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        testOnReturn="true"/>

</Context>
```

- When start server, on the console we see the following 3 times in a row

> 

```
AbandonedObjectPool is used
(org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool@11aa58b)
    LogAbandoned: true
    RemoveAbandoned: true
    RemoveAbandonedTimeout: 60
```

- Application then fails to find the JNDI resource
- If we remove the `<Resource>` in `server.xml`, then the console shows no connection pool is created at all
- On another developer machine with the same hardware and OS we do not have this problem

Any ideas?
Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We re-installed postgresql on the machine and the problem got solved somehow.

We're thinking something in the original postgresql config had been messed up and tomcat was failing to connect to the BD somehow. I guess tomcat was simply "trying 3 times", thus the triple output.

Another unsolved mystery...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, Copy the whole `<Context>` from `server.xml` and create a blank `context.xml` inside your web application `META-INF` folder and paste the `<Context>` copied from `server.xml` there.

Restart your application and see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

move

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/ds"
    username="ds"
    password="pass"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ds"  
    auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
    factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" 
    logAbandoned="true" 
    maxActive="30" 
    maxIdle="10" 
    maxWait="1000" 
    removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    testOnReturn="true"/>
```

to server.xml namely the

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
```

element

in your conf/context.xml file you would instead specify

```
<ContextLink name="jdbc/ds" global="jdbc/ds"/>
```

and this way, the three contexts will share the same pool.